# Excel : Find value from 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Anyone can help me create formula?
I'm stuck for find value from 2 criteria.
Example
Criteria1 is R2
Criteria2 is C7
**And Result is 5**

Data table:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXEAE.png

Thank you.

Comment: I re-upload data table image for easy view. https://i.postimg.cc/DwbfxBnr/Picture2.png

Comment: Look into Index and Match solutions. There should be plenty around on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Getting the row is very easy, simple `MATCH`:

```
=MATCH(G5,A4:A6)
```

Getting the right column is a bit trickier since you have an awkward 2D array with possible criteria but it's still relatively simple:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:D3=G4)*COLUMN(B1:D3))-COLUMN(B1:D3)+1
```

You could just plug those two numbers into the final `INDEX` formula, or make it a bit less readable with something like:

```
=INDEX(B4:D6,
 MATCH(F5,A4:A6),
 SUMPRODUCT((B1:D3=F4)*COLUMN(B1:D3))-COLUMN(B1:D3)+1)
```

All address based on my screenshot, you can adjust them as required.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer resolve my problem :)